# How to round a product of two columns in a sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

So i have this query

```
SELECT p.id product_id
     , o.id order_id
     , u.id user_id
     , o.quantity
     , o.created_at
     , o.total
     , o.quantity * p.price total
     , o.created_at
     , p.price
     , p.name
     , u.username 
  FROM products p
  LEFT 
  JOIN orders o
    ON o.product_id = p.id
  LEFT 
  JOIN users u
    ON  u.id = o.user_id;
```

I want to round the multiplication done here

```
o.quantity * p.price AS total
```

but the ROUND() function will not take

```
ROUND(o.quantity * p.price AS total, 2)
```

and this didn't work either

```
o.quantity * p.price AS total, ROUND(total, 2)
```

how can I round the product ot o.quantity and p.price within the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
ROUND(orders.quantity * products.price, 2)  AS total
```

You alias the column after you're done defining the **entire** column ... you can't alias a part of the column ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

ROUND((o.quantity * p.price),2) AS total

I hope your problem will slove.